# Change the location of an icon in the menu bar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Every time I start up [Radium](http://www.catpigstudios.com/) the menu bar icon for the application shows up in the same place: dead smack in the middle of all my other menu bar icons. Doesn't matter if it's the last menu bar occupying application I've started.

I'd like to have it appear as the icon furthest to left on account of it displaying song information in the menu bar area once I start streaming a station with it.

Is this possible?

I tried a few key + click combinations to see if that would let me drag it around but no luck. It seems stuck in this position.

Edit: I did try a <kbd>Command</kbd>+click to move it -- no luck. Same for <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> click combinations.

The image below show the current location of the icon. I'd like it to appear to the left of the Sparrow icon.

[image: Radium menu bar icon]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If a menu icon is allowed to move, <kbd>command</kbd> + mouse select will work.

You might have to patch the program (or System Ui Server). Have you asked the developer if they can implement this as a feature?

Only the Apple icons are movable on my 10.6.7 systems so it certainly isn't easy for a developer to get this working and may be impossible in practice.

The only workaround would be to have a script that delays the radium start as the leftmost item is the last to load. If you had a launch script that slept for 3 minutes and then killed, relaunched that app - it would be leftmost until another started... If it was really important, you could kill and relaunch it periodically every X minutes to ensure that over time it's the leftmost icon without you taking manual action.

Comment: Unfortunately cmd+click doesn't work. Also: Radium is started manually, so well after every other menu bar occupying application has started up. Either OS X or the app seems to remember the menu bar icon's location and place it in the middle every time.

Comment: I have had issues when the preference that stores the ordering is malformed. Have you tried moving `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist` to the desktop or the trash and logging out/in again to reset the ordering?

Comment: no luck. Still shows up in the same spot on my menu bar. I talked to the dev and he said it's impossible for apps to allow menu bar icons to be moved but he thought starting it last should place the icon last. Oh well.

Comment: Sorry to hear - I was afraid there was no API to replicate the behavior of official Mac OS X icons in the menu bar. Every system I have access to is amenable to the last launched app showing up on the left - but I don't use any of your apps. Skitch, Twitterrific, Take Five, BusyCal and Screens work well together. I hope you find a cause or workaround.

Answer (score 7):

While not a free option, the 1.0 release of [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) allows you to move *any* menu bar item around, including system items such as the clock, notification center, and the battery indicator.

Comment: Hmm, that does sound like a nice utility, but asking $15 for something that only does one small task is quite steep.  They should make it $2 and sell it in the App Store.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a fan of adding more clutter (i.e. use extra apps) to de-clutter or organize something + most of solutions do not work well in EL Capitan.
My personal annoyance was Fantastical icon separated from clock. What I found is that menubar icons order loosely follows respective app launching order, i.e. first launched app takes right-most spot, next to OS X system icons space.

All I had to do is re-arrage login items order and menubar icons got in their desired places. 
OS X system icons (clock, wifi, battery) still can be re-arranged using CMD-drag.

[image]

p.s. to re-arrange login items you'd have to delete and re-add them. No biggie, just Apple-way of doing things lately :)

Comment: +1 This is a solid workaround. I completely agree with your opening sentence.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free app for hiding and reordering icons: [Broomstick](http://www.zibity.com/goodies.html)

Answer (score 0):

While not able to reorder items as requested in the OP, the free app [Dozer](https://github.com/Mortennn/Dozer/) allows you to <kbd>⌘</kbd>-drag position two separators also in the menu bar. The icons to the left of one can be hidden/shown with a click or automatically. Already liking this after my first 10 minute test drive of this app.