# Is there a way to reorder the Mac Menu Bar?

Tags: macos, mac, menu-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the location of an icon in the menu bar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/change-the-location-of-an-icon-in-the-menu-bar)

The title is sort of self-explanatory. I wanted to group some icons into a more logical and useful layout. This question was [last asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15961/change-the-location-of-an-icon-in-the-menu-bar?rq=1) (afaik) during Snow Leopard days. Perhaps there are new methods.

Currently, my menu bar looks like this:

[image]

and I'd like to move the icons on the left over to the right...

Comment: I referred to that question above...

Comment: The question you refer to is not specific to Snow Leopard (nor should it be), so there is no reason you should duplicate it. There are other ways of trying to get attention to an older question available, like editing it, commenting, or starting a bounty.

Comment: understood. I did get a great answer though :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As explained in the referred question, hold down Command key, press the icon in your menu bar, move it. This works at least in Mountain Lion up to Yosemite. But still this only works for movable items. You can move the Wifi symbol, the Bluetooth symbol, etc. But you cannot move the Twitter or Dropbox symbol.

Comment: Thanks, that works with a few as you say. I was sort of hoping for some load-order capability.

Comment: Just figured out that there is a commercial solution to customise your menu bar: http://www.macbartender.com It promises to enable reordering and comes with a free trial.

Comment: brilliant.. Thanks a ton!! I will try the 4 week freebie, but I'll mark this as solved.. Thanks again.

Comment: Macbartender is absolutely perfect. Just what I needed. It's also on sale until 10/25/12

Comment: But what if the icon you most want to move IS Dropbox?

Comment: @radven Bartender, or bust.

Comment: Oh, this funcionality has broken for some apps in El Capitan. You can still reposition most system icons

Comment: It's OK. Couldn't move Google Drive icon. Uninstalled.

Comment: @espinchi broken?! No. They are created by host processes and instances of the `NSStatusItem` class of the SDK. The draggable items are instances `NSMenuExtra` which belongs to a private API, thus apps that use this would be rejected from the App Store.

Comment: It seems that in Sierra you can move all items now.