# Are there any tools to group Menu Bar icons similar to Windows Taskbar?

Tags: icon, menu-bar, ventura

In Windows, we can take certain icons out from the taskbar and an up arrow is shown. It can be clicked to show all the icons. I have attached a screenshot of it below.

I have looked into tools like Bartender, which were recommended in other questions, but it just hides some icons. I don't want to hide any icons. They need to be visible at the click of a button, as shown in the image attached below.

Are there any tools that do the same on Mac? I have tried Dozer, but it only hides some icons. I want all of them to be visible, but only after clicking a specific icon.

[image]

Comment: Technically, what you’re seeing there is the ***System Tray Icons*** (not Task Bar Items; those are different)  and the [Windows Taskbar settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-use-the-taskbar-in-windows-0657a50f-0cc7-dbfd-ae6b-05020b195b07) allow you to set them as *On*, *Off*, or *Hidden*.  That “group” is the *Hidden Icon Menu*. Basically, Bartender does this same function by *hiding* menu bar items.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444113/how-to-prevent-macbook-pro-notch-from-hiding-menu-bar-icons-from-the-right https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69500/is-there-a-way-to-reorder-the-mac-menu-bar